# How can i convert this code to swift 4?

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift4

How can i convert this code to swift 4? I think this code is written in swift 2. I do not understand much. I downloaded Xcode 8, but I could not migrate. I thought to turn it into Swift 3 and then Swift 4, but I did not succeed. Will you tell me in a clear way or translate it?

```
NSCalendar *gregCalrendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [gregCalrendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromdate:[NSDate date]];

[dateComponent setYear:2012];
[dateComponent setMonth:9];
[dateComponent setDay:28];
[dateComponent setHour:16];
[dateComponent setMinute:11];

UIDatePicker *dd = [[UIDatePiclet alloc]init];
[dd setDate:[gregCalrendar dateFromComponents:dateComponent]];


UILocalNotification *notification: [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification setAlertBody:@"UMUT CAN ALPARSLAN"];
[notification setFireDate:dd.date];
[notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notificaion]];
```

Comment: this code is in Objective-c, you can convert it in swift using https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/ you have to do minor changes

Comment: All of theses methods exist in Swift 4. Look for them in the documentation. When available prefer the equivalent class without the prefix "NS". Come back when you have a more specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UILocalNotification` is deprecated. Try this code:

```
    let gregCalrendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    var dateComponent = gregCalrendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: Date())

    dateComponent.year = 2012
    dateComponent.month = 9
    dateComponent.day = 28
    dateComponent.hour = 16
    dateComponent.minute = 11

    let dd = UIDatePicker()
    dd.setDate(gregCalrendar.date(from: dateComponent)!, animated: true)

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "UMUT CAN ALPARSLAN"

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponent, repeats:false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "uniqueId", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

Also you need to add `import UserNotifications` on the top